# Property 'webpackHot' does not exist on type 'ImportMeta'

Tags: typescript, webpack

When setting up webpack 5 / typescript using esm modules I get the error: `Property 'webpackHot' does not exist on type 'ImportMeta'`.  However as far as I can see it seems that it is actually correctly working and hot reloading, it only fails on the TS type check and seems like a false error.

In package.json I have `"type": "module"`, in webpack config I have the normal `hot: true` enabled.  In my dev.ts I do:

```
...
if (import.meta.webpackHot) {
  import.meta.webpackHot.accept()
}
...
```

It is however correctly checking types for everything else, it's only this specific thing that's breaking.  Is there some additional types library that I need? Does webpack 5 automatically install the import.meta.webpackHot type? I am not sure why this is erroring.

https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/

On the official documentation they also show to use it like that, but it ends up breaking with typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just removing the `import.meta.webpackHot` completely.  It seems it's unnecessary when using webpack's hot reload and react-refresh.  It also correctly reloads in browser without refreshing the whole page.  Maybe that helps someone in the future.  As for fixing the above error without deleting it, no idea, but this is probably the better approach.